# Liferay Exception Data while persistance update

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I'm using Liferay with ServiceBuilder but trying to read a code file into String and saving it into the DB, using the update method, I get this error:

```
   return irRulePersistence.update(rule, false);
```

**Error: Data exception error truncated to the left.**

I created this column with the service.xml file:

```
 <column name="ruleFile" type="String" />
```

Is there any other type required for saving long Strings?

Can I save a .drl file into the DB? If yes, what can I do? Is there any guide explaining that?

Thank you so much,
Oriol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For storing long string , you can have entry in portlet-model-hints.xml as

```
<field name="description" type="String">
            <hint-collection name="CLOB" />
```

```
<column name="file" type="Blob" />
```

You can use type Blob to store file to DB.
You can refer to DBStore.java -->updateFile for detail

Comment: Thank you! And... Do you know how to create a column for saving a file for example a .doc or .drl?? This doesn't function: <column name="ruleFile" type="File" />